# Read only access to svn repository via ssh (svn+ssh)

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, permissions

We desire to make subversion repositories read only. Doing this for a single repository in a subversion instance did not work regarding ssh. ssh access appears to bypass the controls of svn.

Followed the suggestions here:
[Read-only access of Subversion repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523823/read-only-access-of-subversion-repository)

Write access should be restricted but that did not happen.
The repository is still write accessible despite changes to the repository for read only.

Comment: ssh or really svn+ssh:// ?! For `svn+ssh://` all svnserve-specific rules (authz file) are applicable

Comment: Read carefully http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-up-svn (p. 8 mostly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to restrict access (assuming there are no users who require write access) is to remove the `w` (write) bit on the files in the SVN repo.

```
chmod -R gou-w /path/to/svn-repo
```

That will prevent writes at the filesystem / OS level.

If some users still require access, you can create separate `svn+ssh` endpoints for each user class that map to different users on the host server, using group write vs other write bits to determine which group has access to affect writes:

```
mkgrp writers-grp
chgrp -R writers-grp /path/to/svn-repo
chmod ug+w /path/to/svn-repo
chmod o-w /path/to/svn-repo
```

I would then register the SSH keys for writers against the writing user on the server, and prevent password access.

The "read-only" users could be allowed a well-known password.

This isn't as "clever" or "elegant" as configuring the SVN server configs, but it works pretty darned well as long as the users keep their SSH keys secret.

Comment: I did something simpler and it works fine. An elegant solution is not required in our case. We are decommissioning the svn instances. However, some instances have a few hundred repositories and we need to block write access. Some developers seem to forget to stop using subversion once we have migrated to Git.  Normally a more elegant approach is needed and it is good that you mention that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Restrict commit access with a [start-commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) hook.

> #### Description
>
> The start-commit hook is run before the commit transaction is even
>   created. It is typically used to decide whether the user has commit
>   privileges at all.
>
> If the start-commit hook program returns a nonzero exit value, the
>   commit is stopped before the commit transaction is even created, and
>   anything printed to stderr is marshalled back to the client.
>
> #### Input Parameter(s)
>
> The command-line arguments passed to the hook program, in order, are:
>
> 1. Repository path
> 2. Authenticated username attempting the commit
> 3. Colon-separated list of capabilities that a client passes to the server, including depth, mergeinfo, and log-revprops (new in
>      Subversion 1.5).
>
> #### Common uses
>
> - Access control (e.g., temporarily lock out commits for some reason).
> - A means to allow access only from clients that have certain
>     capabilities.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. The response will be customized based on a hook. This is definitely more appropriate for a long term solution. In our case subversion will be decommissioned altogether in a short time frame.